# Using variables for a CSS animation? (multiple divs using a fade, but I want them to fade to different values)

Tags: html, css

So I have 4 divs, I want one to fade to 1, another to fade to 0.8, and so on. 
I have

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
   from { opacity: 0 }
   to { opacity: 1 }
}
```

with the opacity of each div set to 1, 0.8, 0.6, etc. Is there a way I can make it so they go their desired opacity without them all fading to 1 then snapping to whatever their value is on their element?

Comment: Single shot? Use `transition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use a keyframe animation for this when you could use [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Here's a working example (with no JavaScript!).

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

input:checked+div {
  opacity: 1;
}

input:checked+div+div {
  opacity: .8;
}

input:checked+div+div+div {
  opacity: .6;
}

input:checked+div+div+div+div {
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
Fade: <input type="checkbox" />
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you!
Say I wanted to do this with width, would it work the same? Like 4 divs growing in from the left? 
(Sorry, i am not at my PC right now so cant test)

Comment: Yes, you can transition on `width` and many other properties.